# How to download history git messages list

Tags: git

As the title, I need download all git commit message list (not download the code)

The result txt like :

```
date message
2018-01-03 fix bugs.
2018-01-02 init joke model.
```

I remember `git` could do this, but I didn't found the solution.

Comment: Did you mean `git log`?

Comment: @user6537157 No, git log include many useless infomation.

Comment: You can specify the output format of `git log`...

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set a log format and shorten the date:

```
git log --pretty='format:%ad %s' --date=short
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print each commit on a single line, use:

```
git log --pretty=oneline
```

If you want to generate the output for machine parsing, you can use option **format**

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"
```

%h for Commit Hash

%an for Author Name

%ar for Author date, relative

%s for Subject

There are many other options available, that can be used with the **format** option.